# Getting compiler error: Request for member push in pq, which is of non-class type std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am getting below error:

> :60:8: error: request for member 'push' in 'pq', which is of
> non-class type 'std::priority_queue,
> std::vector >, std::function, std::pair)> >(comparator)'   60 |     pq.push(p1);

My code is as below:
Declared a comparator for priority_queue as below:

```
class comparator
{
    bool operator ()(std::pair<int, int> &p, std::pair<int, int> &q)
    {
        return (p.second < q.second);
    }

};
```

Declared priority queue as below:

```
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, vector<std::pair<int, int>>, std::function<bool(pair<int, int>, pair<int, int>)>> pq(comparator);
```

make pair as below:

```
auto p1 = make_pair(1, 3);
```

pushed it to priority_queue as:

```
pq.push(p1);
```

Can anyone please tell, what i am doing wrong here

Comment: What do expect passing `comparator`, which is a type, not a value/object, to the constructor?

Comment: What you have a `pq` is a function declaration, taking a single unnamed parameter of type `comparator` (as the error says, if you look closely). The comparator needs to be passed as a template parameter, not function parameter.

Comment: @user17732522 Not really vexing, I think. That's usually when there are two possible interpretations, and the compiler picks the annoying one.

Comment: The `comparator` will also not work, because the `operator()` is `private` and not `const`. Maybe have a look at an example using a custom comparator again.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. That was my mistake. I corrected it. But still getting same error.

Answer (score 3):

- The `operator()` must be `public` and should also be `const` qualified.
- You don't need `std::function` here. Just supply the `comparator` as the third template parameter directly.

```
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct comparator {
    // must be public and should be const qualified:
    bool operator()(std::pair<int, int> &p, std::pair<int, int> &q) const {
        return p.second < q.second;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>,
                        comparator> // <- the proper comparator
     pq;

    auto p1 = std::make_pair(1, 3);

    pq.push(p1);
}
```

Comment: @user2020560 Glad to hear it. You're welcome!